# Translation of "to warp" in the nautical sense?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico

I was reading [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasa_(ship)#Maiden_voyage) when I came across a new (to me) word meaning:

> *The ship was **warped** (hauled by anchor) along the eastern waterfront of the city to the southern side of the harbor*

Upon further investigation, it turns out the English verb "[to warp](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/warp)" has a specific meaning in the nautical world:

> To move (a ship) along by hauling on a rope attached to a stationary object on shore.

The [translations offered by Google](https://translate.google.com/#en/es/to%20warp) (*deformar*, *torcer*, even *pervertir*) are mostly relative to the main meaning of "to become twisted or bent". It also includes *alabear* which seems to have something to do with woodworking -- not relevant.

Some Spanish words like *remolcar* or *jalar* are related to this, but they do not convey the full meaning.

Is there a word in Spanish that can be used to translate "to warp" in its nautical meaning?

Comment: A ver si me entero... veo que esto del _warping_ consiste en que el propio barco tira un ancla o lo que sea a una distancia, y luego recoge el cable para así irse "arrastrando a sí mismo" hacia la posición donde ha caído el ancla. ¿Es así?

Comment: ¿Y por qué afirmas entonces que "remolcar" no vale? Según el DLE es "tirar de una embarcación por medio de un cabo". ¿Cuál sería la diferencia con "warp"?

Comment: I think _remolcar_ is closer to the English word tow which is not the same as warping. To warp you fix the end of the rope somewhere then pull your self along to it, detach the rope and re-fix it further awayand repeat until you have got where you want.

Comment: The crucial thing for me is that you have three things: the boat, a fixed point, someone (or something) pulling. Just exactly where the people are situated is not crucial although they would usually be on board. If the fixed point is an anchor they will necessarily be on board and if they are using a winch that would be on board.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Buscando en un [diccionario náutico](http://www.libreriadenautica.com/diccionario_nautico.html) me he topado con esta palabra que parece describir bastante bien lo que estás buscando:

> **Sirgar**: Llevar una embarcación remolcándola desde la costa con un
>   cabo.

Después he buscado la palabra de marras en el DLE:

> [**sirgar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Y0oYy2c)
>
> 1. tr. Llevar a la sirga una embarcación.

Y de aquí pasamos a *sirga* y la locución *a la sirga:*

> [**sirga**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Y0oJO0H%7CY0oYy2c%7CY0qLy4c)
>
> 1. *f. Mar.* Maroma que sirve para tirar las redes, para llevar las embarcaciones desde tierra, principalmente en la navegación fluvial, y
>      para otros usos.
>
> **a la sirga**
>
> 1. *loc. adv. Mar.* Dicho de navegar: Tirando de una sirga desde la orilla.

Comment: El fragmento de la wikipedia que has puesto dice "arrastrar por el ancla" y aquí es con una cuerda pero la acción parece coincidir en lo demás.